# Как заменить один символ на другой в адресной строке?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Суть проблемы такова: приходит запрос на php фаил вида http://mysite.ru/example.php#variable=1;

`$_GET['variable']` не срабатывает, т.к. в адресной строке стоит "#", а не "?".

Как заменить "#" на "?" ?

гугл дал понять, что возможно это можно сделать в .htaccess, но правильной записи в нем сделать так и не удалось.

Comment: Может просто заменить `# на ?` на клиенте? Хеш не передаётся на сервер.

Comment: Доступа к клиенту, скажем так нет. Имеем только адресную строку, необходимо сделать парсинг данных после символа "#"

Comment: А второе предложение прочитать?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133023/hash-url-rewrite-in-htaccess